# Compare length of values of a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with 20 columns, two of the columns being Company1 and Company2. I want a resultant data frame with only those rows in which length of Company1 and Company2 don't differ by more than 5 characters. How do I accomplish this task using pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.str.len()` to get access to the number of characters in the `Company` columns, then calculate the difference with vectorized subtraction of pandas series and create a logic vector with the condition for subsetting:

```
df[abs(df.Company1.str.len() - df.Company2.str.len()) <= 5]
```